# How to add expand/collapse chrome type for all web parts?

Tags: web-part

Is there a way to add your own customized chrome types to all WebParts?

We need some DIV structure around the web parts to make a expand/collapse effect, so
that a user can click on a "plus" icon and the web part expands or "minus" icon to collapse the web part, [like in this example](http://pr0digy.com/sandbox/mootools/slide-effect/).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to by overriding the web part. However it's probably simpler to just add the required script into your page.

Searching for "expand collapse web parts" shows several examples:

- [Path to SharePoint](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/10/25/expandcollapse-buttons-for-your-web-parts/) (Christophe)
- [moblog](http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2009/08/sharepoint-expand-or-collapse-web-parts.html) (Ben)
- [Ironworks](http://fitandfinish.ironworks.com/2010/02/how-to-expand-collapse-web-parts-in-sharepoint-using-jquery.html) (Brandon Anderson)